# Receptor-Ligand R-package for visualization

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat

I was wondering if there was any R-package for receptor-ligand interaction similar to SingleCellSignal (https://github.com/SCA-IRCM/SingleCellSignalR_v1/blob/master/SingleCellSignalR/vignettes/UsersGuide.Rmd)

+++ if there are vignettes and/or the graphs can be customized.

+++ if it can be linked to Seurat

Note: I have tried iTALK, but I keep getting an error that seems to be a common problem and have left a query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two nice tools for receptor-ligand interaction analysis are:

- [CellPhoneDB](https://www.cellphonedb.org) by the Teichmann lab, although this is not an R package...
- [NicheNet](https://github.com/saeyslab/nichenetr) by the Saeys group

Note that these tools are mainly meant for analysis of receptor-ligand interactions, although I think NicheNet also has some visualization options. CellPhoneDB needs to be run from a shell, but the results can easily be imported into R for visualization. You might check the papers on these 2 methods for some ideas of visualization. Combining Seurat's visualization options and ggplot2 should get you already pretty far.